# 14.04 does not boot after otherwise successful dual boot with windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Have ASUS X551M Notebook PC.  Boots Windows 8.1 Want to dual boot Ubuntu.  Need clarification on Bios setup.  What does "BIOS" add boot option really want when it says it wants a format of fs0:\path\filename.efi? hd0,gpt7 Doesn't look like the right format but neither does "Windows Boot Manager (P0: HGST HTS545050A7E680)" which is option 1 and the only option.  Nor does it look like or "P1: TSSTcorp CDDVDW SN-208FB" which is available for the DVD if I enable CSM (Compatibility Support Mode) to boot from the Ubuntu Live DVD.

It is difficult to formulate a simple question when I don't know what I need to know to fix the problem.  I could not find a better description of "BIOS" settings from either ASUS or American Megatrends. Aptio Setup Utility version 2.15.1236 (c) 2013 bios version 504

I have tried to describe what I have done.  GRUB2 should be able to chainload to windows if I could get to it.  I cannot read/see hd0,Gpt6 so don't know if a *.efi file exists there.   How does Bios settings Boot Override work?  It claims to search for a shell.efi from the file system but doesn't find one.  Any pointers to other sources will be appreciated.  Thanks for your consideration.

Trying to dual boot 64 bit pre-installed Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04 Intel x86 for the Celeron N2830 64 bit CPU in my ASUS X551M Notebook PC.  Install went well but PC boots only to Windows.

from:http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/, guided by the following text:
{"There are two images available, each for a different type of computer:
PC (Intel x86) desktop image For almost all PCs. This includes most machines with Intel/AMD/etc type processors and almost all computers that run Microsoft 
Windows, as well as newer Apple Macintosh systems based on Intel processors. Choose this if you are at all unsure.
64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image Choose this to take full advantage of computers based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture (e.g., Athlon64, Opteron, EM64T Xeon, Core 2). If you have a non-64-bit processor made by AMD, or if you need full support for 32-bit code, use the Intel x86 images instead."
}
I chose Intel x86 for the Celeron N2830 64 bit CPU in my ASUS X551M Notebook PC, downloaded the .iso file and burned a Live DVD.  Changed "BIOS" settings to enable CSM (Compatibility Support Mode) and disable secure boot in order to boot from the DVD and try Ubuntu worked fine.  When I started an install, there was no option to install alongside windows 8.1.  I backed out, rebooted to 8.1 and made a usb recovery drive.  The next install from the Ubuntu Live DVD gave me the option to install Ubuntu alongside 8.1 which I chose.  The install offered to split the available disk space 50/50 or use a gui to change it to something else which I did.  The install proceeded as expected from my experience with Ubuntu12.04 and completed grub-install then asked for a reboot.

There was no grub menu and the reboot proceeded to Windows.

```
Post install, gparted reports the following:
Partition   FileSystem  Mount Point Label   Size    Used    Unused      Flags
/dev/sda1   fat32               SYSTEM  100MiB  29.46MiB70.54MiB    boot
/dev/sda2   ntfs                Recovery900MiB  287MiB  612MiB    hidden,diag
/dev/sda3 ! unknown                 128MiB  --- ---       msftres
/dev/sda4   ntfs                OS  304GiB  29.0GiB 275GiB       msftdata
/dev/sda6 ! unknown                 1.00MiB --- ---     bios_grub
/dev/sda7   ext4  media/ubuntu/UUID         136GiB  5.48GiB 131GiB  
/dev/sda8   linux-swap              3.89GiB 4KiB    3.89GiB
/dev/sda5   ntfs                Restore 20GiB   8.76GiB 11.25Gib   hidden,diag
```

NOTE:UUID for /dev/sda7 above is for the partition
/dev/sda1 is EFI SYSTEM Partition (ESP).
"BIOS" add boot option says it wants a format of fs0:\path\filename.efi. 
do I need to add a boot option of the form P0:\part7?   How would I specify partition7 in windoweze? 
Boot Override in "Save Changes and Exit" lists
Windows Boot Manager (P0: HGST HTS545050A7E680)     This is the internal hard drive
P1: TSSTcorp CDDVDW SN-208FB                This is the internal DVD
UEFI: Crucial Gizmo! 1100               This is the Windows 8.1 16GB recovery thumb drive
Crucial Gizmo! 1100                 This is an 8 GB thumb drive I was using to save data from the live Ubuntu O/S

From grub.cfg in gpt7 viewed by Ubuntu Live from the DVD, the following lines:

```
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  My-UUID  as listed by gparted above
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root My-UUID  as listed by gparted above
fi
```

seem to indicate that grub is prepared to boot Ubuntu by EFI if given the opportunity.

I suspect that gpt6 holds a clue with flag bios_grub. This may be the starting point for grub but I don't know how to point the "BIOS" to this location.  Most other problems I read can't get into windows.  I can get into Ubuntu only from the Live DVD and if I enable CSM.  I have tried with both CSM enabled and disabled but don't get to grub.

New:
The following terminal results of the installed Ubuntu system from the Live DVD indicate that there is no sys/firmware/efi and no boot/efi which might indicate a non efi installation.  However, the image on disk is not a running Ubuntu system so perhaps their lack is explained by these files being created at boot time.  Is it possible to chroot into gpt7 from the live DVD and should I expect that to help?  I notice some of the suggested diagnostics are Linux commands but believe they provide answers only to the running system.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls /media/ubuntu/"UUID-of-/dev/sda7"/boot
abi-3.13.0-24-generic     initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic  memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-3.13.0-24-generic  memtest86+.bin                System.map-3.13.0-24-generic
grub                      memtest86+.elf                vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls /media/ubuntu/"UUID-of-/dev/sda7"/boot/grub
fonts  gfxblacklist.txt  grub.cfg  grubenv  i386-pc  locale
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls /media/ubuntu/"UUID-of-/dev/sda7"/sys
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls /media/ubuntu/"UUID-of-/dev/sda7"/mnt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls /media/ubuntu/"UUID-of-/dev/sda7"/media
```

Comment: If system is UEFI you need the 64 bit version of Ubuntu not the 32 bit. Only the 64 bit version supports UEFI. UEFI & BIOS are two totally different ways to boot computer and it is much easier if you install both operating systems in the same boot mode. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system AND https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 1):

Success.
The Grub menu has Ubuntu first and the Windows Boot Manager second.  Both boot fine from the Grub menu.  System setup is a third option.

1 The x64 iso indeed was the correct choice in spite of the description at http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/.  Many thanks to ubfan1 for clearly stating that fact.

2 Both Ubuntu_Gnome and Ubuntu 64 bit failed to see 8.1 but could proceed to "something else".

3 My "bios" settings has in "Save & Exit" an option titled "Boot Override". That was very important in my case because it was very difficult to get into "bios" (f2 during POST) or the bios boot menu(esc during POST).  Although not initiallaly apparent to me, it works as follows: Normally only the Windows Boot Manager appeared here.  However if the UEFI DVD is in the drive on power up then it also shows up here.  When it is displayed, selecting it and pressing enter starts the boot from the DVD.

4 Thanks to [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) under the subtitle "Windows 8 + Ubuntu" for the Windows alternate route to the UEFI Firmware Settings ie bios.  This was more reliable than f2 during POST.

5 In the "something else" GUI The buttons operate on a selected partition or unallocated space.  The change button permits modification of a partition.  I needed to do this to define the mount point as / for the unix partition.

6 The AskUbuntu site is a wonderful resource.  Many thanks to the many answers.

I'm still learning how this site works.  I hope "Answer" is the correct choice between edit, comment, and answer.  This text confirms the first answer and provides additional data that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your early on wrong choice left you in an impossible situation.

1. Use the 64 bit AMD iso, NOT the 32 bit one, that will never dual
   boot on most UEFI machines in UEFI mode.
2. Windows is in UEFI mode,
       you must run Ubuntu in UEFI mode.  If you can install is in UEFI
       mode, do so.  Try a USB live media if the DVD (with a 64 iso on it)
       really does not boot in UEFI mode.  Some machine really will not
       boot the Ubuntu install media in UEFI mode, so those (rare?)machines
       need to install in compatibility mode, and then use boot-repair to
       switch back to UEFI mode.
3. All the UEFI bootloaders get put into a
       FAT filesystem on the EFI partition.  Looking at them should not be
       a problem for anything which can mount a FAT filesystem
       (everything!).
4. BIOS boot which jumps to the Master Boot Block,
       then jumps to some binary blob outside of any filesystem is no
       longer needed unless you intend to install to a removable media
       which might be used on a non-UEFI machine.  Both BIOS and UEFI boot
       mechanisms may be present, but having both may confuse some machines
       (into using the wrong one).  Your sda6 flagged bios-grub is the
       non-filesystem partition for the guts of the old BIOS boot, don't
       look there for anything.  Look for the Ubuntu UEFI bootloaders in
       the EFI partition under /EFI/ubuntu.  They should be named
       shimx64.efi and grubx64.efi (maybe no shim if you're not using
       secure boot).

Read these:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported
```

UEFI is a new world, but if the vendors had not messed things up so badly, it would be an improvement.
New:
Thank you very much ubfan1 for the answer.  I will burn a DVD with the 64 bit iso, remove the old intelx86 partitions with gparted and reinstall.  The wording at http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/
led me to believe the x64 iso was only for AMD or EM64T processors.